# How to display hints in html form fields?

Tags: javascript, html, hint

I have a very long php form which is used to save input values entered by users.
I want to show hints next to the input boxes. I know this [HTML input field hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280034/html-input-field-hint)
but this is not my goal, i want to show it next to the input boxes which will appear/disappear when ever user selects the respective field. (i want this in html not in javascript etc because i do not know JavaScript.)

Comment: javascript is not the same as java

Comment: Java an Javascript are 2 totally different languages. Besides you can't change your HTML to show/hide something without Javascript.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use HTML5 and use textfields like

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter input" title="Enter input here">
```

Comment: OP wants it next to the input

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with the `:focus` CSS pseudo-class. Put a span next to the input box and give it this style:

```
.hint { display: none; }
input:focus + .hint { display: inline; }
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/inilot/1/edit

Answer (score 8):

You can use `title` argument like this :

`<input title="hint" ... />`

Comment: `title` works in other html tags too, e.g. `<td>`

Answer (score 5):

This is a CSS technique without using any Java{script} code:

```
<style>
.ami div {display:none}
.ami:hover div {display:block}
</style>
<a class=ami href="#">Please hover me <div>I show only when you over</div></a>
</html>
```

Hope I Help