# How to hook shortcut in order to insert some chars inside simple box

Tags: java, macos, hook

I have a a simple `Web` form that i need to provide `User` and `Password` when login, instead of type them again and again when i want to login there is some way that i can click on some shortcut and this will send the string into to `User` section and hit `Tab` and than send the string into `Password` section ? (i am working on `osx`)

I know `Selenium` but i am lookinf for other way.n

Comment: Possbile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280034/html-input-field-hint.

Comment: this is not what i am asked

Comment: So, your question is about application testing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information about technology which you use.

Behavior that you described (picking user name and getting saved password after hitting tab key) is native browser functionality.

Also you have to remember about proper field naming which tells your browser where it should be injected. e.g . If you use field with name email it should let you use emails from other sites. After submiting data browser should ask you if you want to store your credentials. Chrome also supports saving credentials using AJAX.

Programming function which stores your credentials is called RememberMe but it doesnt send any kind of information to the user becasue it would be security breach.